# Android: How to update an item inside a custom list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom list view which is being popluated via an array adaptor.

Each item/row contains three buttons and some related textViews.
All elements in a row describe the details for a device on the cloud. So data is fetched from the cloud and then the list is populated. No. of rows is equal of the number of devices.

Everything was fine till I added the feature for a periodic update for the items. 
The problem is that after each periodic update it over writes the data for a device in the wrong row.
I tried two ways to refresh each row.

1. I kept a map for (DeviceID and view) and then based on the deviceId
   i would get the view and update it. Now,this didn't work as the views are reused and so as i scroll
   down, basically the same view is reused as shows the new data. And
   so the map entry of the previous device is over written with the new
   one.
2. I tried to directly call `getView()` and pass the position but that
   also didn't work.

I understand that the views are reused so there is no way to know exactly which view is associated with a deviceID. 
But could some please help me figure out how to update the correct view with the correct data?

Thanks.

Comment: [Maintaing position of re-used view will help you out](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If you are using Holder pattern, then there is a way to do this.***

*Step 1:* Add one attribute i.e. position to Holder.

```
private class ViewHolder {
       ....
       ....
       int position;
}
```

Step 2: Initialise the holder position into getView()

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {             
           ...             
           holder.position = position;      
    }
....
}
```

*Step 3:* Check holder position and view's position values. If both are same then do your task.

```
if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
       // This is you required row. Do your task. 
}
```

---

Read [***Async loading***](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) for more details.

Comment: ok got that...but for updating do i just call getItem() and specify the position that i want to update? how does that work

Comment: No i want to update items like checkbox and textviews inside some row based on the position. SO when i want to do that do i just call getItem() for that position

Comment: Yes then check position of holder.position and getView's position. If both matched then update view.